# Precision as a metric for information retrieval

Tags: python, information-retrieval, precision-recall

I am working on Information Retrieval (i.e., a user searches for something and then the algorithm returns the top closest hits based on the pre-generated embeddings. I have a corpus of all papers. The idea is it returns the top papers that are closest to the user's query).

At the moment, I have the recall metric. Does it make sense to also calculate the precision metric in this scenario?
I followed really closely this tutorial: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/semantic-search/semantic_search_quora_hnswlib.py (It does not have precision as a metric in here neither)

```
def search_queries():
    print("Corpus loaded with {} sentences / embeddings".format(len(corpus_sentences)))
    input_query = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    query_embedding = model.encode(input_query)

    # hnswlib knn_query method is used to find the top_k_hits
    # knn_query make a batch query for k closest elements for each element of the query
    corpus_ids, distances = index.knn_query(query_embedding, k=top_k_hits)

     # extract corpus ids and scores for the first query
    hits = [{'corpus_id': id, 'score': 1-score} for id, score in zip(corpus_ids[0], distances[0])]
    hits = sorted(hits, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)

    print("Input query:", input_query)
    for hit in hits[0:top_k_hits]:
        print("\t{:.2f}\t{}".format(hit['score'], corpus_sentences[hit['corpus_id']]))   
    print("\n")
    

    # Approximate Nearest Neighbor (ANN) is not exact, it might miss entries with high cosine similarity
    # Here, we compute the recall and precision of ANN compared to the exact results
    correct_hits = util.semantic_search(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings, top_k=top_k_hits)[0] 
    correct_hits_ids = set([hit['corpus_id'] for hit in correct_hits]) # get the id of relevant documents

    retrieved_hits_ids = set([hit['corpus_id'] for hit in hits]) #set(hit['corpus_id'] for hit in hits[0:top_k_hits])
    if len(retrieved_hits_ids) != len(correct_hits_ids):
        print("Approximate Nearest Neighbor returned a different number of results than expected")
    
    
    # Precision 
    # Percentage of all relevant documents that is returned by search
    precision = len(retrieved_hits_ids.intersection(correct_hits_ids)) / len(retrieved_hits_ids) 
                # correct results / all returned results         
    print("\nPrecision: {:.2f}".format(top_k_hits, precision * 100))
      
        
    # Recall
    # Percentage of relevant documents that are successfully retrieved 
    recall = len(retrieved_hits_ids.intersection(correct_hits_ids)) / len(correct_hits_ids) 
                # correct results / all results should be returned 
    print("\nRecall: {:.2f}".format(top_k_hits, recall * 100))

    if recall < 1:
        print("Missing relevant results:")
        for hit in correct_hits[0:top_k_hits]:
            if hit['corpus_id'] not in retrieved_hits_ids:
                print("\t{:.2f}\t{}".format(hit['score'], corpus_sentences[hit['corpus_id']]))
    print("\n\n=======\n")
```

With the above code I wrote for precision, the precision and recall score is always the same and I cannot figure out how to solve this. Any suggestions or insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the length of your corpus and the value of `top_k_hits`? If  `top_k_hits >= len(corpus_ids)` then `correct_hits` would include all corpus_ids and the denominator in your precision and recall metrics would be the same and hence precision would equal recall.

Comment: @ame, thank you so much for your answer. my top_k_hits = 10 and len(corpus_ids) are 10,000. If I understood correctly, in this case, the precision will always equal with recall? What would be a way to tackle this and retrieve the precision score?

Comment: With those values - unless both are 0 - I would expect precision and recall to be different.

Comment: I think your issue originates in this line: `correct_hits = util.semantic_search(querry_embedding, corpus_embeddings, top_k=top_k_hits)[0] `. Having looked at the code for `util.semantic_search` it seems that this will return an object with the shape (n_queries, top_k_hits) and you're looking at the first element in this i.e. the 10 top hits for the first query. Is that what correct / what you expect?

Comment: Yes..  but then I really do not understand why my precision and recall are always the same

Comment: That is weird and unexpected. Normally I'd expect to aggregate precision / recall over many queries against the corpus and it doesn't appear that you're doing that.

Comment: @ame, to answer your above question, yes it returns the top 10 hits for the first query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228989/discussion-between-ame-and-tlqn).